# Mgt Development Environment - MySQL suddenly won't start

Tags: mysql, docker

I have 4 containers using `mgt-commerce/mgt-development-environment-7.2`. Basically everything runs well until I cannot access the control panel. It returns `500`.

After checking the services, logs, etc, it seems like mysql is unable to start. Here is the error log captured in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` during starting mysql service using `sudo service mysql start`.

```
2019-09-26T23:38:43.740283Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2019-09-26T23:38:43.921450Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.26-29) starting as process 1576 ...
2019-09-26T23:38:43.924613Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-09-26T23:38:43.924635Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-09-26T23:38:43.924639Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-09-26T23:38:43.924642Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-09-26T23:38:43.924644Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-09-26T23:38:43.924647Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-09-26T23:38:43.924859Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-09-26T23:38:43.924920Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-09-26T23:38:43.925849Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 1G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2019-09-26T23:38:43.946744Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-09-26T23:38:43.955252Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-09-26T23:38:43.966654Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Recovering partial pages from the parallel doublewrite buffer at /var/lib/mysql/xb_doublewrite
2019-09-26T23:38:44.033822Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-09-26T23:38:44.033986Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2019-09-26T23:38:44.034023Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2019-09-26T23:38:44.034040Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2019-09-26T23:38:45.135220Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-09-26T23:38:45.135270Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-09-26T23:38:45.135283Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2019-09-26T23:38:45.135291Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-09-26T23:38:45.135301Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-09-26T23:38:45.135371Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-09-26T23:38:45.136207Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Is there anyone using this image ever getting this kind of error?

**Update**

It seems like mysql doesn't have the access to a particular file(s) or directory(ies), but I'm not sure which file(s) or directory(ies) . Here is the permission of mysql data directory:

```
clp@magento2dev:/$ ls -la /var/lib | grep mysql
drwxr-x--- 1 mysql         mysql         4096 Sep 26 23:38 mysql
drwxrwx--- 2 mysql         mysql         4096 Jul 11 15:24 mysql-files
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql         mysql         4096 Jul 11 15:24 mysql-keyring
```

Comment: My guess is you need Write permission in /var/lib/mysql directory since startup is trying to cover a 'doublewrite' abnormal condition according to the error log.

Comment: @WilsonHauck you should have seen that the permission should be correct. Owner & group of Mysql data dirs and their subdirs, including files inside, has already set to mysql:mysql. I also have made sure that everything is already set by executing `sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql -R`

Comment: About 15 lines up, appears to me to be MISSING the 'w' permission.  I have been wrong before.

Comment: @WilsonHauck but every files inside the `/var/lib/mysql` has `rwx` permission for owner, including the `/var/lib/mysql/xb_doublewrite` file